# facebook photo size when posting from inside ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just want to post an image to Facebook. With the following code, I am able to do that, but the image I post is correctly shown when watching at Faceebook web page, instead when watching at Facebook app, the image is much bigger than its actual size.

```
grahPath = @"me/photos";
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo) forKey:@"source"];
[params setObject:captation forKey:@"message"];
[self graphFacebookForMethodPOST:grahPath params:params callback:callback];
```

Could you please tell me where I am wrong?
If more info is needed, just tell me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problems. Same issue also with Twitter. I asked Twitter and Facebook developer to be 100% sure.
The best way to post image on social from inside an app is to post an high resolution image with a medium/big size so that even if Facebook or Twitter resize it, it won't loose quality.
Issue closed.